# Does anybody know the composition of the 6th council and how the delegates were chosen?

Tags: history

Nyanatiloka and Nyanaponika were the only Western born monks to attend the 6th Council. I am curious to know the composition of the 6th council and how the delegates were chosen.

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_Buddhist_council):

> The council was attended by 2,500 monastics from eight Theravada Buddhist countries.

Clearly there would have been more countries involved than the 8 Buddhist countries. Also the delegates from countries which were not predominantly Buddhist sponsored by a Buddhist country they lived in. Also how come Nanamoli Bhikkhu and Ven. Ñāṇavīra Thera did not make it as delegates?

Comment: May be you can contact the owner of this website, http://www.aathaapi.net/AboutMentor.php
He has a record of events from the 6th council. I remember he mentioned, monks from even Pakistan participated in the council. Monks from Japan have also been there.

Comment: http://store.pariyatti.org/Cha77897789ha-Sa7749g257yana-Souvenir-Album--PDF_p_4427.html a download of this PDF shall probably help you.

Comment: @SumindaSirinathSalpitikorala  Reference : [The Six Dhamma Councils](http://stylomilo.com/files/mv/YMBADip/Dhamma/The%20Six%20Buddhist%20Councils%20-%20LTY.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I have been asking around and done some research, but got nothing specific to answer your questions. Some years ago I spoke with an elder Norwegian Buddhist, who said that no less than 12 countries(to his knowledge) was present, plus a number of schools from each country. He said that extra invitations were sent out by the original invited and that this was allowed. A bit like how the Buddhist UN conferences work - just without all the fancy food... :)